# Informix crosstab query

Tags: sql, informix

I have a table with the following data

```
resourceid     skillname       Competence 
ckent          Flight          9 
ckent          Heat Vision     8 
ckent          Strength        10
tstark         Flight          6 
tstark         Genius          8
tstark         Missiles        9
```

I need to crosstab this table in Informix SQL so that the result is:

```
resourceid     skill1    comp1  skill2         comp2 skill3     comp3
ckent          Flight    9      Heat Vision    8     Strength   10
tstark         Flight    6      Genius         8     Missiles   9
```

I have tried select with group by resourceid with max(case when skillname like '%') as skill1 min(case when skillname like '%') as skill2 but cannot get more than 2 skills to display.

Comment: Suppose you also have lines `hpotter, Magic, 9` and `hpotter, Quidditch, 9`; what should be shown in the result given that Superman and Ironman have three skills and competence levels to Harry's two?  What should be the result if you have an extra line `tstark, Money, 8`?  Is there a required order for which entries appear in `skill1` and `comp1` — alphabetic by skill name, perhaps?

Comment: Alphabetic by skill name would be best

Comment: That's an answer to the third question — what about the other two?